# What is this type diode & transistor?

Tags: transistors, diodes

im new in electronic.

i don't know 2 this component:

1. maybe this is Diode Marking ST S56 Z424

[image: Marking ST S56 Z424]

i can't found reference this part. can anyone give me a link reference or similar part?

2. Transistor, Marking  FR5505 P417D

[image: Transistor, Marking FR5505 P417D]

i found referensi this part 55v 18A, but in my country nothing shell this item. can i replace with IRF9Z34N 55v 19A?

thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1):

2) Yes, that is almost certainly a good substitution, the parts are nearly identical.

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfr5505pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356358535210f
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9z34nspbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153561228de1de0

If you suspect that the gate isn't driven hard, also look at the Vds I-V curves. The replacement is more sensitive, this is good.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) This is the power schottky rectifier [STPS5L60S](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stps5l60.pdf) from ST

2) mattman944 gave an excellent comparison

With regards to repairing: Be sure you not only fix the *result* of the problem (replacing the broken components) but also the *cause* of the problem (why was the component broken in the first place? Are there more broken components that are not visually broken?).